# Prove that $\sin x \cdot \sin (2x) \cdot \sin(3x) < \tfrac{9}{16}$ for all $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, derivatives, inequality

> **Prove that**
>   $$ \sin (x) \cdot \sin (2x) \cdot \sin(3x) < \dfrac{9}{16} \quad \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}$$

I thought about using derivatives, but it would be too lengthy.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Derivatives sound like a good way to solve this. You should give it a try!

Comment: Wolfram says $max(sin(x).sin(3x))=\frac{9}{16}$ for a certain x at which sin(x) isn't 1. Doesn't seem easy to prove though

Comment: The period of that function is $2\pi$, so one way to go about it could be to graph the function in that interval and then check the value of the maximum. Another way to attack this would be to expand $sin(2x)$ and $sin(3x)$, and then work with the resulting expression.

Comment: Note that this is a weak result. You maximize the function by solving quartics etc and getting $x\approx0.6879$ giving $0.5487<\frac{9}{16}$, so they are probably looking for some trick to come up with the weaker result.

Comment: Since the maximum of $\sin(x)\cdot\sin(3x)$ is $\frac{9}{16}$ (still quite lengthy to calculate) and $\sin(2x)$ has a maximum value of $1$, you are left to proof, that there is no $x_0$ where $\sin(2x_0)=1$ and $\sin(x_0)\cdot\sin(3x_0)=\frac{9}{16}$, which would mean the expression is never $\geq \frac{9}{16}$.

Comment: What is amazing is that, playing with a few trigonometric identities, the derivative can write $2 \sin ^2(x) (4 \cos (2 x)+3 \cos (4 x)+2)$ from which we can easily get $\cos(2x)$ then $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{3} \left(8-\sqrt{10}\right)}$ which is almagest's result.

Comment: @Coodey This approach at first glance ignores the fact that the factors might be negative. The max of $-\sin x\sin 3x$ is $1$ (at $x=\pi/2$, for example)

Answer (score 11):

One has
$$2\sin x\sin(3x)=\cos(2x)-\cos(4x)\ ,$$
and therefore
$$2\sin x\sin(2x)\sin(3x)=(1+u-2u^2)\sqrt{1-u^2}=:f(u)\qquad(-1\leq u\leq1)\ ,$$
where we have put $\cos(2x)=:u$. One computes
$$\sqrt{1-u^2}f'(u)=6u^3-2u^2-5u+1$$
with zeros at $$u\in\left\{1, -{\sqrt{10}+2\over6},{\sqrt{10}-2\over6}\right\}\ .$$
The third of these leads to the maximal value of $f(u)$, which we then have to divide by $2$. The result can be simplified to
$$\sin x\sin(2x)\sin(3x)\leq{68+5\sqrt{10}\over108\sqrt{2}}\doteq0.548737<{9\over16}\ .$$

Answer (score 9):

We have the following equality:

$$ \sin(x) \sin(3x) = \frac{\cos(3x - x) - \cos(3x + x)}{2} = \frac{\cos(2x) - \cos(4x)}{2} = \frac{c - 2c^2 + 1}{2} $$

where $ c = \cos(2x) $. The function $ f(x) = -2x^2 + x + 1 $ attains its global maximum at $ x = 1/4 $, which means that we have

$$ \sin(x)\sin(2x)\sin(3x) \leq \sin(x)\sin(3x) = \frac{f(\cos(2x))}{2} \leq \frac{f(1/4)}{2} = \frac{9}{16} $$

if at most one of $ \sin(x), \sin(2x), \sin(3x) $ are negative.

Note: To show that the inequality is strict, it suffices to observe that $ \sin(2x) < 1 $ when $ \cos(2x) = 1/4 $.

**There should be some way to fix this solution so it applies more generally. I will revisit this answer sometime in the future if I find such an argument. If you find a way, feel free to suggest an edit.**

Comment: @K.Power This is not easily seen because it is not true in this generality: For $x=\frac54\pi$ we have $\sin x>0$, $\sin 2x<0$, $\sin 3x<0$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thank you I see that is true. I was too hasty in assuming the truth of the inequality.

Comment: @Starfall Your edit is only correct if the minimum of $f(\cos(2x))$ is greater than $-f(1/4)$